# Capturing the browser console messages in ruby selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, console.log

The below code will log the console messages from the browser, you can save that in a file.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
def test
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path= File.expand_path("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
  @browser.window.maximize
  @browser.goto("http://3qilabs.com/how_to/check-for-javascript-errors-on-a-page-with-ruby-and-selenium-webdriver/")
  arr2 = @browser.driver.manage.logs
  puts arr2.get(:browser)

end
test()
```

Comment: That looks more like an answer rather than a question. What is the problem?

Comment: Thought this code will help others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an answer rather than a question.  It should be posted as an answer to a question.  If no appropriate question already exists, you are encouraged to create your own question and then answer it (yes, that's perfectly allowed).